# How to assign a new icon to a pager?

Tags: paging, javascript

The current default pager in [Views Paging](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Views_Paging) Drupalgap is easily neglected.

> [image: screenshot]

Can I assign it a new icon or create my own pager button? Currently, what I know is to put it at the top or the bottom using `pager_pos: 'bottom'`, but nothing else.

Comment: Did you try taking over the `theme_pager_link()` function in your theme? http://api.drupalgap.org/7/global.html#theme_pager_link - For example, implement: `my_theme_pager_link()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw the `theme_pager_next` the text is `text: '&raquo;',`. Do you mean I modify that in `src/modules/views/views.js`?

Comment: I modified `bin/drupalgap.min.js` and it works, but it seems not very appropriate to change this file. Is there a place I can put my custom theme_pager?

Comment: I meant copy the contents of `theme_pager_link()`, and then create a new function called `my_theme_pager_link()` in your theme's .js file, then when it comes time to render, DrupalGap  we'll see if the active theme is overriding that particular theme function, then it'll use that instead of the core one. That way you don't have to modify core.

Comment: thanks. by the way, in your document http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Themes/Create_a_Custom_Theme, there's a typo in the footer code. `'data-position': 'b'`, it should be `'data-theme': 'b'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tyler. I follow his suggestion and have solved this by adding the theme_pager_link() to `app/themes/my_theme/my_theme.js`. Here is what I added:

```
function my_theme_pager_next(variables) {
  try {
    var html;
    variables.page = parseInt(variables.results.view.page) + 1;
    var link_vars = {
      text: 'Next Page',
      attributes: {
        'class': 'pager_next',
        'data-icon': 'fast-forward'
      }
    };
    html = theme_pager_link(variables, link_vars);
    return html;
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('my_theme_pager_next - ' + error); }
}

function my_theme_pager_previous(variables) {
  try {
    var html;
    variables.page = parseInt(variables.results.view.page) - 1;
    var link_vars = {
      text: 'Previous Page',
      attributes: {
        'class': 'pager_previous',
        'data-icon': 'fast-backward'
      }
    };
    html = theme_pager_link(variables, link_vars);
    return html;
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('my_theme_pager_previous - ' + error); }
}
```

now the pager become like this:
[image]